# Gstreamer video to opengl texture

Tags: android, opengl-es, gstreamer

I'm trying to render AV frames grabbed and converted from a MPEG4 video using Gstreamer to an Android (2.2)-opengl texture. I've pretty much exhausted google and not found an answer.

Basically, I am using Gstreamer uridecodebin to decode the frame, and then convert the frame to RGB, and then `glTexSubImage2D()` to create an openGL texture from it, but can't seem to get anything to work.The texture is getting colored when I get the decoded data (RGB) from Gstreamer.

I am getting the video size as `320 * 256` and my Texture size is `512 * 256` & I am using `glDrawTexiOES(0,0,videowidth,videoheight)`, I am not getting any errors related to opengl, but the texture is blank( different color frames), though the Audio works fine.

Here is my code:Native OnDraw:

```
if (theGStPixelBuffer != 0) {

    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, s_texture);

    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri (GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glPixelStorei( GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 2);

    glTexSubImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, theTexWidth,
        theTexHeight, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        GST_BUFFER_DATA(theGStPixelBuffer));

    check_gl_error("glTexSubImage2D");

    theGStPixelBuffer = 0;

}

glDrawTexiOES(0, 0, 0, theTexWidth, theTexHeight);
check_gl_error("glDrawTexiOES")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have encounter the same problem ;you can get the bitmap and use martix class to resize the bitmap.